Brenier's Level set formulation of a particular 1D scalar conservation law
Consider the scalar conservation law
\begin{equation} \label{eq:scalar_conservation_law} \tag{1}
    \begin{cases} 
        \partial_t F_t(x) + \partial_x Q(F_t(x)) = 0, \qquad t \ge 0, x \in \mathbb R, \\
        F_t|_{t = 0} = F_0 \in L_{\operatorname{loc}}^1(\mathbb R)
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
with $F_t \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $Q \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.
I choose $Q(a) = 1 - 2 a$ and $F_0 = 1_{[0, \infty)}$. It is known that the unique entropy (or: Kruzhkov) solution of \eqref{eq:scalar_conservation_law} is
\begin{equation*}
    F_t \colon \mathbb R \to [0, 1], \qquad
    x \mapsto \begin{cases}
        0, & x < - t, \\
        \frac{x + t}{2 t}, & | x | \le t, \\
        1, & x > t.
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
The main theorem (Thm. 2.3) of Brenier's 2009 paper $L^2$ formulation of multidimensional scalar conservation laws states that a one-parameter family of entropy solutions to \eqref{eq:scalar_conservation_law} can be recovered from the solution $(Y_t)_t$ of the $L^2$-Cauchy problem
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{cases}
        0 \in \partial_t Y_t(a, x) + Q'(a) \partial_x Y_t(a, x) + \partial \iota_K(Y_t), \qquad Y_t \in L_2([0, 1] \times \mathbb T), \\
        Y_t|_{t = 0} \in L^{\infty}([0, 1] \times \mathbb T) \cap K,
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
where $K \:= \{ Z \in L^2([0, 1] \times \mathbb T: \partial_a Z(a, x) \ge 0 \ \forall (a, x) \in [0, 1] \times \mathbb T \}$, by
\begin{equation*}
    F_t(y, x)
    = \int_{0}^{1} H(y - Y(t, a, x)) \; \textrm{d}a
    \in [0, 1], \qquad y \in \mathbb R
\end{equation*}
and all entropy solutions with $F_0 \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$ can be recovered this way (up to rescaling).
I am interested how in this specific case the solution $(Y_t)$ looks like. More precisely, my questions are:
My question

As entropy (aka Kruzhkov) solutions to \eqref{eq:scalar_conservation_law} are unique I do not quite understand why there should be a family of entropy solutions?
Is $H = 1_{[0, \infty)}$?
Using the method of characteristics (and ignoring $\partial \iota_K$), I obtain the solution
\begin{equation*}
    Y_t(a, x)
    = Y_0(a, x - (1 - 2 a) t).
\end{equation*}
But what is the $Y_0$ corresponding to my choice of $F_0$? Apparently, I can recover $Y_0$ from $F_0(y, \cdot)$, but I do not know that $F_0(y, \cdot)$ should be.

